# NSURLConnection 60 sec timeout max for GET?

Tags: objective-c, timeout, nsurlconnection

I am using RestKit for my project, and i need timeout for my request something like 10-20 minutes(600 - 1200 sec.)
I am able to change timeout from 1 to 60 sec  and this works without any issues. But when I try to set more that 60 sec (90-9999999)  i receive timeout error after 60 seconds. There is such code in RKRequest.m :

```
- (void)fireAsynchronousRequest {
    RKLogDebug(@"Sending asynchronous %@ request to URL %@.", [self HTTPMethod], [[self URL] absoluteString]);
    if (![self prepareURLRequest]) {
        // TODO: Logging
        return;
    }
    _isLoading = YES;

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidStartLoad:)]) {
        [self.delegate requestDidStartLoad:self];
    }

    RKResponse* response = [[[RKResponse alloc] initWithRequest:self] autorelease];

    _connection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:_URLRequest delegate:response] retain];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:RKRequestSentNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

I added one line before NSURLConnection init:

```
[_URLRequest setTimeoutInterval:1200];
```

But received timeout error again after 60 sec. RKResponse object is delegate for NSURLconnection. 
So I found that after 60 sec delegate metod in RKResponce.m is called (even I try to init NSURLConnection object after [_URLRequest setTimeoutInterval:1200])  :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    RKResponseIgnoreDelegateIfCancelled();
    _failureError = [error retain];
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
    [_request invalidateTimeoutTimer];
    [_request didFailLoadWithError:_failureError];
}
```

Its strange for me that I can't make timeout for NSURLConnection more that 60 sec.

Today i created new project to test this issue. I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://5.9.10.68:8182"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:300.0];
    NSLog(@"timeout %f",urlRequest.timeoutInterval);

    NSURLConnection*  urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate: self];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Error request %@", error);

}
```

So here is the log:

2012-07-17 14:37:58.627 f[76799:f803] timeout 300.000000
2012-07-17 14:39:14.488 f[76799:f803] Error request Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x687a690 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://5.9.10.68:8182/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://5.9.10.68:8182/, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x687a070 "The request timed out."}

So timeout = 75, but not 300. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this way?

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://somewhere.com"];
objectManager.client.timeoutInterval = 600;
```

Comment: actually my code looks like:    `RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString:aBaseURL];
    manager.client.timeoutInterval = 300;`  But i found out that its not RestKit issue.Also i found related to this problem: [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/852)